# Password_cracker using python

Tags: python

I want to create a create a zip file password cracker(4-lengths only)and come up with this code,
now the problem is FileNotFoundError is showing at line no. 14 why is it so? I have the zip file in my same folder, think that this is code.py file I have the easy.zip file in same folder, image also provided, how to fix the error? Any code suggestions/improvements will also be appreciated,NOTE - I don't know whether the code runs or not if you find any bug then please kindly report it to me!!!

```
import zipfile
charlist = 'abcdefghijklmmopqrstuvwxyz'

get_password = []

for current in range(4):
    decrypt = [i for i in charlist]
    for x in range(current):
        decrypt = [y + i for i in charlist for y in decrypt]

    get_password = get_password + decrypt


unlock_file = zipfile.ZipFile('easy.zip')#here is where the exception occurs

attempts = 0

    for password in get_password:
        try:
            attempts += 1
            unlock_file.setpassword(password.encode('ascii'))
            unlock_file.extract('easy.txt')
            print(f'Password successfully found after {attempts} attempts and the password is {password}')
            break
        except:
            pass
```

[image: See the image also provided]

Comment: if you want to crack bigger passwords you will run out of memory soon, rewrite your program and fix your indenting

Comment: I think it needs the absolute path. You need to copy the full file path and try again.

Comment: You need to put `easy.zip` in the folder you are running the script in, in this case `C:\Users\Ankit Mitra\Desktop\New folder`, not where the script is. Or you need to go into the directory where your script is and run it from there. The point is that when you have a relative path, it's relative from where you're running the script not where the script is. If it worked the way you seem to expect, then you'd have to move all files where your scripts are or use absolute paths, which would be really tedious.

Comment: Still not working try running the code yourself

Comment: your current working directory is `New Folder` (great name). This is not where the zip file is. Change your `launch.json` (`cwd` parameter) or use `hacking/easy.zip`